# OpenCV - How to divide one RGB image by another?

Tags: c++, opencv, floating-point, division, mat

I am trying to divide an RGB image by another RGB image, element-wise.
But the results are not correct.
This is what I have tried:

```c
    img1 = imread("some RGB image");
    img2 = imread("some RGB image");
    Mat division(img1.size(), CV_32FC3, 0.0);
    Mat img1F, img2F;
    cvtColor(img1, img1F, CV_32F);
    cvtColor(img2, img2F, CV_32F);
    divide(img1F, img2F, division);

    //-- see results
    vector<Mat> Channels(3), img1Channels(3), img2Channels(3);
    split(division, Channels);
    split(img1F, img1Channels);
    split(img2F, img2Channels);

    for (int i = 0; i < division.cols; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < division.rows; j++)
            if ((Channels[2].at<float>(j, i)) != 0) {
                cout << "img1F: " << img1Channels[2].at<float>(j, i) << endl;
                cout << "img2F: " << img2Channels[2].at<float>(j, i) << endl;
                cout << "division: " << Channels[2].at<float>(j, i) << endl;
            }
```

The results I am getting are very strange. For example:

```
img1F: -2147483648
img2F: -2147483648
division: -1.29988e+31
```

What I expect is for example:

```
img1F: 50
img2F: 200
division: 0.25
```

Comment: `cvtColor` use is wrong, if you want to convert `uint8_t` -> `float` use `cv::Mat::convertTo`.

Comment: @rafix07 thank you. it fixed the problem.